# "-m" not visible when using Git in Windows Terminal

Tags: colors, invisible, windows-terminal

I'm using Windows Terminal and I'm having trouble with Git, when I type `-m` it's invisible:

[image: Screenshot]

I've tried modifying the `.gitconfig` file but haven't managed to find the parameter to that specific thing. How can I change it?

Comment: Or if you have another `-m`, it can be a conflict between the colouring of your shell (cmd, powershel, git bash, bash/fish/zsh/... in wsl or whatever) and Windows Terminal. What shell do you use? What are your settings for that shell? What are the settings of Windows Terminal? Does it work in conhost?

Comment: This isn't *Git* (which doesn't colorize input commands on its own, as it literally can't) but rather some colorization feature your shell provides. What shell are you using? (Incidentally this is one of those rare cases where a screenshot is required, since presumably the invisible `-m` is actually there if you cut-and-paste. It's just being displayed as black text, on your black background.)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a PowerShell theme issue - check the output of `Get-PSReadLineOption` - if you see any invisible colors:

[PowerShell invisible colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ful4D.png)

You can fix this by specifying your own colors - e.g: `Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{ 'Number' = "blue"; 'Member' = "DarkGray"}`